# How construct http request to create facebook's open graph object from iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, curl, afnetworking

I want to create Facebook open graph object by sending http request from my app, I don't use Facebook SDK, I'm using Social Network Framework and construct requests to open graph with AFNetworking. My code:

```
    - (void)didInitializeSocialAccountStore:(BOOL)succes forPermissions:(AccountStorePermissions)permissionsType
    {
        NSURLRequest *request = [self requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/objects/myapp:comments?access_token=%@", [MGSocialNetworkSingleton sharedInstance].facebookAccesToken] parameters:self.exampleObject];

        if (permissionsType == AccountStorePermissions_Publish)
        {

            AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
                DLog(@"response: %@\n", response);
                DLog(@"JSON: %@\n", JSON);
                DLog(@"URL: %@\n", request.URL);
            } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
                DLog(@"response: %@\n", response);
                DLog(@"error: %@\n", error);
                DLog(@"JSON: %@\n", JSON);
                DLog(@"URL: %@\n", response.URL);
            }];
            [operation start];
        }    
}
- (NSDictionary *)exampleObject
{
    return @{@"object":@{@"title":@"Titleeeee"}};
}
```

After request is made I'm getting this error response:

didInitializeSocialAccountStore:forPermissions:]_block_invoke_2 [Line 432] JSON: {
    error =     {
        code = 100;
        message = "(#100) The parameter object is required";
        type = OAuthException;
    };
}

I'm also using this methods:

```
[self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
[self setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
[self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
```

So exampleObject NSDictionary shoud be automatically converted to JSON

**EDIT**

This curl command works fine:

curl -X POST "https://graph.facebook.com/me/objects/myapp:comments" -F "access_token=CAAH3rJC7RHUBAHP6NHGaa5Pr2MKlJT4X9GZBZBkc93T9TNHqoSV411eD2uvOw2XInpZCZBryY4V6OtvHP5xMDZCJfyiieTe8IB1lS68gYkNlKj6bNYfcsPZCGpamC2wWVJDkAYm9hVHI3fASDGxbHKWUQYam8JZAwblA68y8HXZA1v2EaDZAe3VabyJQ37Q5rf6JVpWiRV50dKH9XSa7I7ZAcg9QajPhWnk3PEZD" -F "object={\"title\":\"Titleeeee\"}"

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I used different approach and it works, here is my code, maybe someone won't waste his time for it like I did:

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"title":@"work you f****r"};

NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData
                                             encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/me/objects/website?access_token=%@&object=%@", kMGFacebookAPIBaseURLString, [MGSocialNetworkSingleton sharedInstance].facebookAccesToken, jsonString] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] parameters:nil];
```

it returned:

```
response: {
    id = 709840849042702;
}
```

It's for different graph object (website) but it wasn't a issue here